# Are there any disadvantages to using AJAX as a RIA?

Tags: ajax, jquery, ria

Are there any disadvantages to using AJAX to deliver RIA as opposed to other technologies like Silver Light?

I would also like to mention that you can go further and use Ajax with jQuery to make even better RIA's - would anyone disagree?

Cheers, 
J

Comment: Not really sure how you could compare AJAX with Silverlight. In addition is AJAX really only a small part of a "Rich Internet Application".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AJAX is just the concept of asynchronous calls to the server from websites without reloading the whole page.

Silverlight is a Framework, not even for creating html pages, but for providing "native" Windows applications started from the Web. Do yourself a favor and don't even consider it.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of Silverlight over an HTML/AJAX solution is the speed and ease of development, particularly as your application gets more complex. Whether that's worth the loss of reach depends on your target audience.